# Has UK common budget or every country has its own?

Tags: united-kingdom, budget, finance

How financial system works in UK?
Must England, Scotland, Wales and North Ireland, fill the common budget or every country is completely independent, "keep" his money/profit for itself?
Does the taxes fill the same UK budget or every country has own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Westminster Parliament creates a budget for its responsibilities that covers the whole UK. This budget will include taxes, money from other sources (such as bond sales) and allocations of money.

The government will allocate some money to the Scottish Parliament and Welsh Assembly. It will also allocate some money to county councils in England, and some to Schools etc.

Most of the money that the Scottish government spends comes from the block grant from central taxation. Scotland, for example, is a net beneficiary. In 2020-21, Scotland raised £62.8 billion  in tax  compared to £99.2 billion of public spending for Scotland (this was higher the previous years due to pandemic spending). But generally the flow of money is from the richer parts of the UK towards the poorer, and many of the richer parts are in England.

The local councils will then be able to raise more money from the "community charge" (a property tax).  The Scottish Parliament is also able to raise some money by setting a different income tax to that in England.

The devolved Parliaments and the local authorities will then set their own budget on how they will spend the money on their areas of responsibility. However local authorities are subject to audit by the central government. Other public services will get their own allotment and will set a budget on how it is spent. Each school, hospital trust and police force will have its own budget (but they don't have tax-raising powers)

So the system is mixed.  Most levels of government have some ability to raise money by taxes, but much of the money is collected centrally and allotted to local councils by the central government.

Comment: UK Parliament /government = England Parliament/government, does that mean in practice England get "better conditions" than other 3 countries in UK? The Parliament/government works more in favor of England?

Comment: No the opposite.  UK parliament = UK parliament.  There is no England Parliament. In practice tax money flows from England to the other countries.

Comment: Yes there is not England parliament, but Scotland, Wales and NI have own parliament, so that mean England has/is UK parliament?

Comment: It does mean that some responsiblities of the Scottish Parliament in Scotland (etc) are held by the UK parliament in England.

Comment: So, for example, The UK parliament might decide to spend more money on education in England.  While the Scottish parliament decided to spend less on education in Scotland.   On the other hand the Army funded by the UK government in both Scotland and England.

Comment: England contribute/fill more to budget so has more money to spend comepare to others 3 countries?

Comment: Yes, in general the south east part of the UK is the most wealthy. But there is a lot of local variation.

Comment: But Commonwealth countries don't fill UK budget ? in any way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149664/discussion-between-james-k-and-user628075).

Comment: So, do any English politicians, or prominent people, advocate letting say Scotland cut itself loose from the union during their referendums?  Going by your numbers it seems like it would massively improve finances for the English/remainder of UK.  Scotland itself might do quite well from rejoining the EU, so everyone might benefit.  Worth asking a Q, or just totally un-proposed by anyone sane, ever?

Comment: Hmm does this mean that UK is a *federation* as government structure?

Comment: @Vesper  There are differing opinions on this.  See https://www.centreonconstitutionalchange.ac.uk/news-and-opinion/back-unitary-state.

Comment: @JamesK What are nationalities  of people   in UK parliament and UK government?  Can prime minister of UK be Scot, Walesh or NI or must be only English?

Comment: @user628075 That is a new question. Please don't use the comments to ask new questions.  It is also a very easy question to answer (hint "Gordon Brown")